# Why my ViewModel is still alive after I replaced current fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel, coroutine

Example, If I replaced 'fragmentA' with 'fragmentB', the 'viewModelA' of fragmentA is still live. why ?

## onCreate() of Fragment

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory().create(InvoicesViewModel::class.java)
}
```

## ViewModel

```
class InvoicesViewModel : ViewModel() {

init {
    getInvoices()
}

private fun getInvoices() {

    viewModelScope.launch {

        val response = safeApiCall() {
            // Call API here
        }

        while (true) {
            delay(1000)
            println("Still printing although the fragment of this viewModel destroied")
        }

        if (response is ResultWrapper.Success) {
            // Do work here
        }
    }
}
}
```

## This method used to replace fragment

```
fun replaceFragment(activity: Context, fragment: Fragment, TAG: String) {
    val myContext = activity as AppCompatActivity
    val transaction = myContext.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, TAG)
    transaction.commitNow()
}
```

You will note the while loop inside the Coroutine still work although after replace fragment to another fragment.

Comment: Please post some code to see what you are doing.

Comment: @PFuster Added the code

Comment: Are you initializing `ViewModel` correctly? From the Android docs: `ViewModelProvider(this).get(InvoicesViewModel::class.java)` EDIT just saw the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is about your implementation of `ViewModelProvider`.
use this way for creating your viewModel.

```java
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(InvoicesViewModel::class.java)
}
```

in this way you give your fragment as live scope of view model.

Comment: But, this ViewModelProviders currently deprecated 
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders

Comment: It's deprecated now

Comment: @MahmoudIbrahim yes I checked it now and update my answer

Comment: @MarkKeen Creating ViewModel is not a good idea. One of advantage of view model that is it save your data until your scope alive and if your screen create again you didn't need fetch them again.

Comment: Great, It's solved. Exactly this is the issue, thank you @mahdishahbazi for your answer. but I think you have a typo mistake, please remove the 'new' from your answer because this is Kotlin code.

Comment: @MahmoudIbrahim yes your are write, my open project class was java and I checked it on that :D

Answer (score 0):

Check, if you have created the ViewModel in Activity passing the context of activity or fragment.

Comment: I added snapshoot of the code to the question, please check it.